# How do I get NSOutline view to work with bindings?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview

My goal is to develop a verry simple file browser using NSOutline view.  I already know how to do this normally, but I am totally lost on how to set this up using the binding approach.

When using regular approach i can easily find out the children that are in the parent directory by writing code in the delegate call methods to find the file/folder count and names.. however, with the binding approach, I have to build the NSMutableArray before hand.. so, is there some where i can determine the Child contents of a folder? Any help/direction appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a little sample project which does just that.

- Display a list of items
- Edit the items in a master-detail fashion
- Remove and add items
- Usage of bindings along with a model class (`Book`).

Check out [besi/mac-quickies](http://github.com/besi/mac-quickies/) on github.
Most of the stuff is either done in IB or can be found in the [AppDelegate](https://github.com/besi/mac-quickies/blob/master/OutlineView/OutlineView/AppDelegate.m)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the sample code, but I could already do this. The problem i dont know how to do is... How do i make the sample code you provided to display the directory/file contents of your computer? like a file browser (using bindings)